# Django Rest Framework: Passing Context in Viewsets

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Viewsets are convenient because we can do stuff like this and get a fully working serializer:

```
class StoreObjectViewSet(mixins.ListModelMixin, mixins.RetrieveModelMixin, viewsets.GenericViewSet):
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
    queryset = StoreObject.active_objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.StoreObjectSerializer
```

Unfortunately, as far as I know– to pass the context into the serializer we need to do things like this:

```
PostSerializer(data=request.data, context={'request': request})
```

Which means we need to manually override every convenient method provided by ViewSets (as far as I know). Is there a way to inject the context into every serializer while still keeping Viewsets convenient?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, `request` is being sent to any Generic View and ViewSet. You can check the source code in [GitHub](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/734c534dbb9c5758af335dba1fdbc2690388f076/rest_framework/generics.py#L130) as well. So you do not have to inject them in every view. If you want to pass extra context, then override [**`get_serializer_context(...)`**](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#methods) method:

```
class StoreObjectViewSet(mixins.ListModelMixin, mixins.RetrieveModelMixin, viewsets.GenericViewSet):
    ...

    def get_serializer_context(self):
        context = super().get_serializer_context()
        context['custom_context'] = 'Your custom context'
        return context
```